# How should I interpret parameters of the SARIMA model in time series analysis?

Tags: arima, interpretation, seasonality, intuition, fourier-transform

I am a bit confused as to why the SARIMA model requires four parameters beyond the ARIMA model just to remove the seasonal component from a time series.

Obviously $m$ is required to specify the duration of the period.  It is less clear how $P$, $D$, and $Q$ jointly specify the remainder of the information about seasonality.

Does removing seasonality ultimately consist of removing or quieting certain terms from a frequency domain representation of a time series, in the same mathematical vein as removing a target frequency from audio?  If so, then how would the four parameters $m$, $P$, $D$, and $Q$ relate to targeting a frequency in the audio engineering application?